# Парсер сайта, нужно подсчитать данные из таблицы

Tags: python, парсер

мне нужно подсчитать сколько игроков в сети из данных которые я с парсил с сайта.
Но у меня это не получается, укажите мне на ошибку пожалуйста.
Вот сам код:

```
import discord
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get



fraction = input("Введите номер фракции:")

url = f"https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/8/{fraction}"


headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-agent": "********"
}


req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
all_table = soup.find_all(class_="table")
online = len(all_table('/Сейчас играет/gm')
    
print(online)

print("Фракция:" + fraction)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

С таблицами хорошо справляется модуль `Pandas`, он сам найдёт и распарсит таблицы на сайте, остаётся только отфильтровать нужные строки:

```
import pandas as pd

fraction = input("Введите номер фракции: ")
url = f"https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/8/{fraction}"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
online = df.loc[df[3] == 'Сейчас играет', 1].to_list()
print(f'Фракция {fraction} сейчас играют {len(online)} игроков: {", ".join(online)}')
```

Вывод:

```
Введите номер фракции: 1
Фракция 1 сейчас играют 5 игроков: Harvey_Brown, Gabriel_Adams, Nikita_Podnebesnyy, Christopher_Avgust, Klaver_Klaverov
```